# Double Planet In A Wide Binary Star System

Tags: planets, space

Right now I'm writing a sci-fi story that develops in a double planet (think of Rocheworld.) The double planet (along with a couple more planets) orbit a big star and the whole system is orbited by another star (about 10,000 AU from the central star.)

I need to know how implausible this is. I don't want my story to drift from speculation into the impossible. I'm guessing that the occurrence of such a planetary arrangement is very low likely, but is such a system even possible at all?

Now, if it's possible, how messed up days and seasons in this planet would be? I'm bending my brain to figure out what would be the length of day and night in such a system (since the planets are very close to each other.)

Any help with this will be really appreciated.
[image: Double Everything]

Comment: How long does it take star 2 to revolve around star 1?

Comment: Setting it at approximately 8500 AU from the central star, it would take Star 2 about 450,000 years.

Comment: Is that Earth-years, Star2-years, or some other measurement?

Comment: Earth years. I'm using Universe Sandbox, so don't know how precise it might be.

Comment: Does your diagram imply that the planets are roughly halfway between the stars? Or what is the actual ratio?

Comment: It's not the actual distance ratio. The distance between Star 1 and the planets is about 800 AU since Star 1's mass is about 17 suns.

Comment: I think you should put all those additional infos into the question. Also, are your planets supposed to support life?

Comment: Also, there's something off with the numbers. According to [this calculator](http://www.1728.org/kepler3a.htm) for Kepler's 3rd law, at 8500 AU and 450k years, the combined mass of both stars would only be 3 solar masses. If the total mass is higher, then the distance must be larger and/or the time shorter, otherwise the stars would not be in orbit.

Comment: Also, 10,000 AU is a long ways out. Like 2 light-months. Star 2 will look like a very bright star, but no more. Roughly, its brightness will be 1/100 million that of our sun. Pluto, for instance, only averages about 39 AU from the sun, so star 2 is about 250 times farther away than that.

Comment: 800 AU for the planets is also far outside the star's habitable zone, if the planets are supposed to be able to support life (and there is no significant geothermic energy etc.). The planets would receive on average 0,00015625% of the solar energy they would receive at 1 AU.

Comment: Combining Star 1's mass, density and luminosity, habitable zone occurs farther away than with out sun. Star 1 has similar specs to VY Canis Majoris.

Comment: You *really* start getting into some odd bits with such large stars. When you compare the [sun's spectrum](http://qdl.scs-inc.us/2ndParty/Images/Charles/Sun/SolarSpectrum2_wbg.png) that that of [VY](http://herschel.cf.ac.uk/files/VYCMa_Herschel-SPIRE_hi_annot.png), its *really* **really** ***really*** bright in the short wavelengths. Ripping apart molecules bright. This also ignores that starts of this class are creating a rather large nebula of ejected material.

Comment: I see. I understand what you're saying. Hmm... I'll have to make a better choosing of my stars. I mean, the size of the stars is not really relevant to the story. The important part is that in these planets, days are longer than nights, to a degree that there's almost no night. I read an article saying that wide binary systems are chaotic, hence a planet able to sustain life is really close to impossible.

Comment: If the planets are very close together, what are the *tides* like? I shudder to think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you will need to know is that the planets won't stay together like that.  The closest you could do would be to have them orbiting each other like the Moon and Earth.  Otherwise the inner one will slowly pull away from the outer one until it catches up from behind.

This is because the speed a planet or other object orbits another is based on it's distance from each other, period.  Closer is faster, farther is slower.

In a similar situation, [Janus and Epimethius](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast121/lectures/epimetheus_and_janus.html) are moons of Saturn.  Their orbits are close enough that they don't pass each other, they trade orbits.  If a similar situation happened with Earth, they would trade places about every 5000 years.

Now day/night.  the farther sun would likely be more like a moon depending on the distance and at times it will be on the opposite side of the first star as each one goes around at different speeds.

Comment: I was googling companion orbits for this question and ran into this as well, it's similar to the Janus/Epimethius but a bit different: http://www.universetoday.com/84652/earth-has-a-companion-asteroid-with-a-weird-orbit/

Comment: So, we could say that the only way two planets could stay together like that would be by artificial means. Like some sort of technology. Let's say both planets were in collision course and somehow the inhabitants of planet A managed to join A with B (the colliding one) by using some device.

Comment: @A.CLouis Yes, that is possible.  If you really want them to stay close together like that, having them orbit each other as they orbit the sun might be the way to go.  Catching and holding a planet takes a LOT of energy

Comment: @bowlturner Hmm.. I could work with that. What would it take to catch and hold a planet? I'll surely have to explain how that happened somewhere in the story.

Comment: @A.CLouis  A lot!  We have several people here who could answer that fairly accurately, but I'm not one.    I suspect it would take more energy than can be generated from all our combined nuclear armaments across the planet.  If you control the power to move a planet there isn't much that can threaten you at all.

Answer (score 1):

The day length would depend entirely upon the rotation of the individual planets.

There would be additional periods of darkness during "eclipses", which would depend on the angle and timeframe of the mutual revolution.

Seasons would generally depend upon the angle of the axis of the individual planets.  A fast revolution of the two planets would minimize the variance.  It would be a bit cooler when farther away and warmer when closer, but with a fast mutual revolution, the temp would tend to stabilize towards what it would be at the average distance from the primary.

Answer (score 1):

The formation of a double planet system could in theory be possible without any artificial intervention. In such a system, the gravitational centre lies in the space inbetween the planets outside either planet and as long as their orbital distance exceeds the Roche limit (the distance where the gravitational pull of the planets exceeds their cohesion, ripping them apart) it could be stable. Depending on the orbital distance, these planets could be tidally locked with one another (facing each other with the same hemisphere, like the moon). Partial solar eclipses should be an almost daily event and there should be some "weird" gravitational forces with it's effects being diminished in the space between the planets making flight/space travel less energy demanding or even allowing a tether (space elevator) between the planets. As for the companion star, it is believed that that wide binary systems orbit in highly elliptical orbit with a range of 100-1000 AUs. When the companion star approaches the nearest to the main star, its gravitational pull causes havock to the planetary orbits, sometimes even resulting to the ejection of entire planets.